# Integrating sbt DIST and Assembly commands

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala project for which I have imported the sbt assembly and native packager plugins.

now I can do `sbt assembly` and it builds a fat jar for my project.

what I desire is that if I do `sbt dist` then this fat jar is the one which gets packaged into a native format like a zip file.

however, when I do a `sbt dist` for my project it just builds a zip file with all the jar files. It doesn't pick my fat jar.

The reason I want the fat jar is that the `sbt dist` is blindly packaging everything without any merge strategy and therefore the output fails with errors. My fat jar works fine because I wrote merge strategy in the build.sbt.

But I cannot package my fat jar with the dist command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Add the following to your build.sbt project settings

```
// add this on top of file
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._

// add this to project settings
mappings in Universal := {
  // universalMappings: Seq[(File,String)]
  val universalMappings = (mappings in Universal).value
  val fatJar = (assembly in Compile).value

  // removing means filtering
  // notice the "!" - it means NOT, so only keep those that do NOT have a name ending with "jar"
  val filtered = universalMappings filter {
    case (file, name) =>  ! name.endsWith(".jar")
  }

  // add the fat jar to our sequence of things that we've filtered
  filtered :+ (fatJar -> ("lib/" + fatJar.getName))
```